# 31 bit limit on bit operations in R

Tags: c, r, bit

I am trying to get around the 31-bit limit for bit operations in R. I can do this in pure R, but my issue is about implementing this in C for use in R.

### Example

For example I have the data

```
> x = c(2147028898, 2147515013)
```

where each element is at most 32 bits, unsigned, and on which I'd like to do bit operations such as (but not limited to) `(x >> 20) & 0xFFF`. The end goal would be using many of these kinds of operations in a single function.

The two numbers are of different bit lengths.

```
> log2(x)
[1] 30.99969446331090239255 31.00002107107989246515
```

Normal bitwise operations in R yield the following result, ie NAs are introduced for the larger of the two.

```
> bitwShiftR(x,20)
[1] 2047   NA
Warning message:
In bitwShiftR(x, 20) : NAs introduced by coercion
> bitwAnd(x,20)
[1]  0 NA
Warning message:
In bitwAnd(x, 20) : NAs introduced by coercion
```

### Workaround with R package 'bitops'

The [bitops](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/bitops/index.html)package does what I want, but my end goal is something more advanced, and I want to be able to use C, see below.

```
> library(bitops)
> bitShiftR(x,20)
[1] 2047 2048
```

I have looked at the C code for this package, but I don't really understand it. Does it have to be that complicated, or is that just for optimization for vectorized inputs and outputs?

### Workaround in C (the issue)

My code is as follows, only a simple expression so far. I have tried different types in C, but to no avail.

```
#include <R.h>

void myBitOp(int *x, int *result) {
    *result = (*x >> 20) & 0xFFF;
}
```

which I then compile with `R CMD SHLIB myBitOp.c` on a 64 bit machine.

```
$uname -a
Linux xxxxxxxxx 3.0.74-0.6.8-xen #1 SMP Wed May 15 07:26:33 UTC 2013 (5e244d7) x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

In R I load this with

```
> dyn.load("myBitOp.so")
> myBitOp <- function(x) .C("myBitOp", as.integer(x), as.integer(0))[[2]]
```

When I run the function I get back

```
> myBitOp(x[1])
[1] 2047
> myBitOp(x[2])
Error in myBitOp(x[2]) : NAs in foreign function call (arg 1)
In addition: Warning message:
In myBitOp(x[2]) : NAs introduced by coercion
```

So the question is, why do I get these NAs with this C code, and how do I fix it? The return value will always be much less than 31 bits btw.

Thank you!

### Update

After studying the bitops code a bit more, and going through [this presentation](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/bitops/index.html) among other links I came up with this code (bonus vectorization here)

```
#include <R.h>
#include <Rdefines.h>

SEXP myBitOp(SEXP x) {
    PROTECT (x = AS_NUMERIC(x) ) ;
    double *xx  = NUMERIC_POINTER(x);

    SEXP result = PROTECT(NEW_NUMERIC(length(x)));
    double *xresult = NUMERIC_POINTER(result);

    for( int i=0; i < length(x); i++) {
        xresult[i] =  (double) ((((unsigned int) xx[i]) >> 20) & 0xFFF);
    }
    UNPROTECT(2);

    return(result);
}
```

Compile with `R CMD SHLIB myBitOp.c`

And in R:

```
> dyn.load("myBitOp.so")
> myBitOp <- function(x) .Call("myBitOp", x)
> myBitOp(x)
[1] 2047 2048
```

I don't fully understand why or how yet, but it works, well seems to work for this example at least.

Comment: `as.integer(x) [1] 2147028898         NA`. R doesn't have an unsigned integer type.

Comment: Right, R doesn't have an unsigned integer type, hence the question :). Removing as.integer does't really work, or I have yet to find a combination of datatypes that does work.

Answer (score 1):

The second element of `as.integer(x)` will be `NA` because it's larger than `.Machine$integer.max`.  `NAOK = FALSE` in your call to `.C`, so that `NA` in your input results in an error. Your call to `.C` will "succeed" if you set `NAOK = TRUE` (because, in this case, `NA` is technically `NA_integer_`, which is a special int value in C).

You'll have to be creative to get around this. You could try splitting values > 2^31-1 into two values, pass both of them to C, convert them to unsigned integers, sum them, convert the result to a signed integer, then pass back to R.

Comment: OK, I get a result now, but I also get an annoying warning.. Should I use suppressWarnings and forget about it? :)

Comment: The depends entirely on what you're trying to do. `2147515013` is too large to be represented as a 32-bit signed integer, so R converts it to `NA` before passing it to your C code. So your C code is doing bit operations on `NA`, which may or may not be reasonable for your purposes.

Comment: I don't get it, so R thinks it's NA, but C thinks it's an integer (since it seems to work anyhow), which then R says is a problem, but it might not be? So is there a way to get around this using other datatypes?

Comment: R doesn't "think" it's `NA`. R coerces it to `NA` (technically `NA_integer_`, which is a special int value in C). It may "work" (i.e. return a value), but it's wrong in most cases. I'm sure there are creative ways to get around this using other data types (e.g. split values > 2^31-1 into two values, pass them to C, convert them to unsigned integers, sum them, convert the result to a signed integer, then pass back to R).